# Literature mining tools and methods

Tags: r, literature-search

"As a first step, we sought to systematically establish the complete set of genes implicated in the physiological response to SCI. We conducted a systematic analysis of the SCI literature, reviewing over 500 papers, in order to reveal a set of 695 unique human genes associated with the response to SCI by small-scale experiments (Supplementary file 1). Of these genes, 559 were upregulated following SCI, 213 were downregulated, and the protein products of 8 were differentially phosphorylated. Among all genes, 151 were associated with the response to SCI by more than one study (Figure 2A). The complete set includes genes that have been associated with SCI in a wide range of experimental models of SCI, in addition to human injuries (Figure 2—figure supplement 1A); in multiple species, including human as well as rat, mouse, and rabbit (Figure 2—figure supplement 1B); using a range of experimental techniques (Figure 2B); and at a variety of time points, from 1 hr to 6 months post-injury (Figure 2—figure supplement 1C)."

[Paper](https://elifesciences.org/articles/39188)

I would like to know what kind of tools or specifically R library can be used to this kind of literature mining .